# Hybrid Mobile application development using angularjs, how to give support for local font in older versions of android

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, mobile, hybrid

i am  developing  an hybrid news application.The app displays news in local language.in my case the server response is a json file with some values in regional malayalam[used in the kerala state,india] language. My problem is when ever i build the app for android 2.3.3 ,it is not displays the malayalam language on device.

here is my json structure :

```
[    {
      "liveid":"79",
      "imagename":"download (1).jpg",
      "tittle":"മീനഭരണിയും പെങ്കാലയും",
      "description":"കൊരട്ടി: ചിറങ്ങര ഭഗവതി ക്ഷേത്രത്തിലെ മീന ഭരണിയും പെങ്കാലയും ബുധനാഴ്ച നടക്കും. രാവിലെ 9നാണ് പൊങ്കാല സമര്‍പ്പണം. ഉച്ചയ്ക്ക് അന്നദാനം, വൈകിട്ട് .\r\n",
      "status":"live",
      "courtesy":"",
      "editor":""    } ]
```